# How to prove this trig identity?

Tags: trigonometry

If $A+B+C=\pi$ then prove:$$\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C=2-2\cos A\cos B\cos C$$

I am completely lost on this, please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the law of cosines (Al-Kashi Theorem) ? A, B and C represent the angles of a triangle

Comment: @T_O Where do you have that A,B,C are the angles of triangles?

Comment: Their sum is Pi (180°), and the sum of the angles of any triangle is Pi

Comment: @T_O Not every angle A,B,C which sum to pi, aren't of a triangle.

Comment: It's a way of transposing your problem. If you define (draw) a triangle $XYZ$ for which the angles are A, B and C, you didn't change your problem but now you can apply nice properties due to the fact that you work on a triangle

Comment: @T_O I am not getting what you say. But lets assume its a triangle, then how would you do it?

Comment: I will try to give you an answer within the next 2 hours, I am currently busy and cannot write a proper proof, but I believe combining http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines should give you an elegant answer. It may not work but it's worth a try

Comment: Did you mean $A+B+C=\pi$?

Comment: @robjohn Oh yes!

Comment: @Sawarnik sorry for being late. Actually my proof work but is actually longer than the ones used in the answers below, and uses the same formulas so it is too redundant

Comment: @T_O Ok, no prob :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C=1-\cos^2C+1-(\cos^2A-\sin^2B)$$

Now, $\displaystyle\cos^2A-\sin^2B=\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)=\cos(\pi-C)\cos(A-B)$
$=-\cos C\cos(A-B)$

So, $\displaystyle\cos^2C+\cos^2A-\sin^2B=\cos^2C-\cos C\cos(A-B)$

$\displaystyle=\cos C[\cos C-\cos(A-B)]$

$\displaystyle=\cos C[-\cos(A+B)-\cos(A-B)]$ as $A+B=\pi-C$

Now, $\displaystyle\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)=?$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b

Answer (score 1):

$A+B+C = \pi \implies A + B = \pi - C \implies \sin(A+B)=\sin(C) \land \cos(A+B)=-\cos(C)$

$\sin^2(A) + \sin^2(B) + \sin^2(C) \\ = \sin^2(A) + 1-\cos^2(B) + 1 − \cos^2(A+B) \\ =2+(\sin^2(A)-\cos^2(B))-\cos^2(A+B) \\ = 2+\cos(B-A)\cos(A+B)-\cos(A+B)\cos(A+B) \\ = 2+(\cos(B-A)+\cos(A+B))\cos(A+B) \\ = 2 - 2\cos(A)\cos(B)\cos(C)$