# prove that if $\sin^{2}\alpha+\sin^{2}\beta+\sin^{2}\gamma=2$ then the triangle has a right angle

Tags: trigonometry

prove that if $\sin^{2}\alpha+\sin^{2}\beta+\sin^{2}\gamma=2$ then the triangle has a right angle.

$\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the angles of the triangle.

I tried to use all kinds of trigonometric identities but it didn't work for me. it's to complex form me

Thanks.

Comment: Have you used that $\alpha +\beta +\gamma=\pi?$

Comment: do you mean: $\alpha +\beta +\gamma=\pi$? and yes i did

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce -  but i need to prove directly..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rearranging, we have
$$\sin^2(a) = \cos^2(b) + \cos^2(c)$$
Since $a=\pi-(b+c)$, we get
$$\sin^2(b+c) = \cos^2(b) + \cos^2(c)$$
Hence,
$$(\sin(b)\cos(c) + \cos(b) \sin(c))^2 = \cos^2(b) + \cos^2(c)$$
This gives us
$$\sin(b)\sin(c)\cos(b)\cos(c) = \cos^2(b) \cos^2(c)$$
This means
$$\cos(b) \cos(c) = 0 \text{ or }\cos(b+c) = 0$$
Now conclude what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be the angles of a triangle; then it holds
$$
\boxed{\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta+\sin^2\gamma=2+2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma}
$$
If this equals $2$, we conclude
$$
\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma=0
$$
so one of the angles is a right angle.

#### Proof of the claim

Let's use that $\gamma=\pi-\alpha-\beta$, so $\cos\gamma=-\cos(\alpha+\beta)$. Then
\begin{align}
\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma&=
\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)\\
&=\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta\\
&\qquad-2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\alpha\cos\beta\\
&=\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+1-\cos^2\alpha-\cos^2\beta+2\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta\\
&\qquad-2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\alpha\cos\beta\\
&=1+2\cos\alpha\cos\beta(\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta)\\
&=1-2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma
\end{align}
giving the final relation
$$
\boxed{\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1-2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma}
$$
Now
\begin{align}
\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta+\sin^2\gamma
&=3-\cos^2\alpha-\cos^2\beta-\cos^2\gamma\\
&=2+2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma
\end{align}
as claimed at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b)

$$\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C=1-(\cos^2A-\sin^2B)+1-\cos^2C$$

$$=2-\cos(A-B)\cos(A+B)-\cos C\cos C$$

$$=2-\cos(A-B)\cos(\pi-C)-\cos\{\pi-(A+B)\}\cos C$$

$$=2+\cos(A-B)\cos C+\cos(A+B)\cos C\text{ as }\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$$

$$=2+\cos C[\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)]$$

$$=2+\cos C[2\cos A\cos B]$$

Comment: @gorgi, How about this?

Comment: im not familiar with the sign $\overline$ but it looks nice. thanks!

Comment: @gorgi, Sorry for the confusion. Please find the edited version