# Triangle Identity leads to another Euclidean parallel.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, hyperbolic-geometry

Referring to  [TriangleIdentity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105391/proving-sin2a-equiv-cos2b-cos2c-2-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c) by 伍柒貳 a while ago, considering  $\bigtriangleup$ ABC, it is proved that:

$$\sin^2A \equiv \cos^2B + \cos^2C + 2 \cos A\cos B\cos C (1*) $$

I want to take angle $A = 0$ to look at the angle relationship of parallel lines so created.

From the above $ \cos B + \cos C  = 0  $ gives *two* solutions as :

$$ 2 \cos( \frac {B+C}{2} ) \cos( \frac{B-C}{2} ) = 0  \, (2*) $$

$$ B + C = \pi ; B - C = \pi;  (3*)$$

With $ A + B + C = \pi  $ the first gives Euclid's proposition ( Two parallel lines cut by any transversal,  two angle sum on one side equals $ \pi$)  as expected.

But the second part of (3*) gives

$$ B = \pi - A/2 , \, C = -A/2 $$

The second situation has me stumped. Is the Sine & Cos Triangle Law someway flawed? Is there a seed in it of hyperbolic geometry? Please comment on any related aspect. Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are three "triangle"s  with $\angle A = 0 $ and $AB $ parallel $AC$

- a "triangle"  with $\angle A = 0 $, $\angle B = 0 $ , $\angle C = \pi $
- a "triangle"  with $\angle A = 0 $, $\angle B = \frac{\pi}{2} $ , $\angle C = \frac{\pi}{2} $
- a "triangle"  with $\angle A = 0 $, $\angle B = \pi $ , $\angle C = 0 $

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider the family of triangles $\triangle ABC$ with, say, $|\overline{AB}|$ of fixed length, and $\angle C = k\;\angle B$ for some arbitrary (but positive) $k$. As $\angle A$ shrinks to $0$, vertices $B$ and $C$ certainly converge, but arguably the limiting values of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ are $\pi/(k+1)$ and $k\pi/(k+1)$, respectively. Thus, when $B$ and $C$ coincide in a flat $\triangle ABC$ (your middle case), their angles can be taken as *any* supplementary pair whatsoever; without a limiting context, the best we can say is that those angles are "indeterminate".

Comment: @ Willemein:  $\angle A = 0 $, $\angle B = \alpha $ , $\angle C = \pi- \alpha $ for arbitrary $\alpha$.

Comment: yes you are right, now I am wondering g where the A comes from in "But the second part of (3*) gives $ B=\pi − \frac{A}{2},C=\frac{−A}{2} $ " just a new variable with an old name? but then what is the problem to start with?