# Show that x is independent of this trig expression

Tags: trigonometry

For some reason I cannot get the solution.

Show that $x$ is independent of: $\sin^2(x+y)+\sin^2(x+z)-2\cos(y-z)\sin(x+y)\sin(x+z)$

I have used all the identities but seem to be missing something.

Comment: Hint: do you know the law of cosines?

Comment: Yea the one you use in 2D and 3D problems or another one?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
& \sin^2(x+y)+\sin^2(x+z)-2\cos(y-z)\sin(x+y)\sin(x+z) \\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x+2y)) + \dfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x+2z)) - 2\cos(y-z)\sin(x+y)\sin(x+z)\\
&=1-\cos(2x+y+z)\cos(y-z) -  2\cos(y-z)\sin(x+y)\sin(x+z)\\
&=1-\cos(y-z)\left[\cos(2x+y+z) + 2\sin(x+y)\sin(x+z) \right]\\
&=1-\cos(y-z)\left[\cos(2x+y+z) + \cos(y-z) - \cos(2x+y+z)\right]\\
&=1-\cos^2(y-z)\\
\end{align}$

which is independent of $x.$

Comment: Thanks very much, I was on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2(x+y)+\sin^2(x+z) =1-[\cos^2(x+y)-\sin^2(x+z)]$

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),

$\cos^2(x+y)-\sin^2(x+z)=\cos(2x+y+z)\cos(y-z)$

and then use [Werner formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html), for $2\sin(x+y)\sin(x+z)$