# How to prove this trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I need to prove that $$\cos^2(\beta -\gamma)+ \cos^2( \gamma - \alpha) +\cos^2(\alpha -\beta) = 1+2 \cos(\beta- \gamma) \cos( \gamma - \alpha)\cos(\alpha -\beta)  $$

To do this I have used the formula $2 cos^2 \theta  = 1+ \cos2\theta$

But after using the formula  it seems that, the whole equation is getting complex. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You should use somehow that $\beta-\gamma+\gamma-\alpha+\alpha-\beta=0$

Comment: A slight simplification: let $\gamma - \alpha = x, \alpha - \beta = y$. Then the identity to prove is $$\cos^2(x+y) + \cos^2 x + \cos^2 y = 1 + 2\cos(x+y)\cos x\cos y$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate, My head is totally cranked. I wasted too many pages.

Comment: It's easier then that. See my answer.

Comment: Make sure to ping people with the @ symbol so they know you're talking to them! I assume that you were addressing @marwalix, but his comment is also embodied by my previous one; you can simplify the expression to only have *two* "free variables", instead of three. Anyway, the procedure will be the same, just expand one side until you get the other (like in the answer given). The only thing I meant to accomplish was to tidy up the expressions a bit by getting rid of a dependent variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll rewrite it as
$\cos^2(b -c)+ \cos^2( c - a) +\cos^2(a -b) = 1+2 \cos(b- c) \cos( c - a)\cos(a -b)
$
because I am lazy.

Since
$\cos(2u)
=2\cos^2(u)-1
$
and
$\cos(u)\cos(v)
=\frac12(\cos(u-v)+\cos(u+v))
$,
applying these whenever possible
(without much thinking),

$\begin{array}\\
\cos(b- c) \cos( c - a)\cos(a -b)
&=\frac12(\cos(b-2c+a)+\cos(b-a))\cos(a-b)\\
&=\frac12(\cos(b-2c+a)\cos(a-b)+\cos(b-a)\cos(a-b))\\
&=\frac14((\cos(2b-2c)+\cos(2a-2c))+2\cos^2(b-a))\\
&=\frac14((2\cos^2(b-c)-1)+(2\cos^2(a-c)-1))+2\cos^2(b-a))\\
&=\frac12(\cos^2(b-c)+\cos^2(a-c)-1+\cos^2(b-a))\\
\end{array}
$

Q.E.D.
(to my surprise).

Answer (score 1):

$$F=\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C=\cos^2A-\sin^2B+1+\cos^2C$$

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b), $$F=\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)+1+\cos^2C$$

If $\cos(A+B)=\cos C\iff A+B=2m\pi\pm C,$ (where $m$ is any integer)

$\displaystyle F=\cos C\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)\cos C+1$
$\displaystyle=1+2\cos C[\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)]$
$\displaystyle=1+2\cos A\cos B\cos C$

Set $\beta-\gamma=A,\gamma-\alpha=B,\alpha-\beta=C$