# Prove that $\alpha + \beta=\frac {\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

It is given that-

> (1) $0<\alpha,\beta<90$.
>
> (2) $\sin^2\alpha+\sin^ 2\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta).$

Prove that $\alpha + \beta=\frac {\pi}{2}$

Comment: Is it even possible to satisfy (1) and (2)?

Comment: No, $\sin 30^\circ +\sin 60^\circ=(1+\sqrt3)/2$ is greater than $\sin 90^\circ=1$. How are you checking the validity of the statement?

Comment: I am extremely sorry.Actually I mistyped the question.Please refer to the original edited question.

Comment: Ah. At this point, you might be better off leaving this question as it was and asking a separate question. It's up to you...

Comment: @ChrisCulter Will the new question not be marked as duplicate?

Comment: If you roll back this question so that it reads $\sin\alpha + \sin\beta$ again, the new question shouldn't be marked as a duplicate. The other benefits are that Michael Galuza's answer to this question will still be relevant, and the new question will get more visibility because it won't look like it's been answered already.

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE:** it's answer to initial question (without squares), downvoters.

It's very strightforward.
$$
\sin\alpha + \sin\beta = 2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\\
\sin(\alpha + \beta) = 2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\\
\sin\alpha + \sin\beta = \sin(\alpha + \beta)\Longrightarrow \sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} = 0\text{ or }\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} = \cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}
$$
In the first case
$$
\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} = 0\Longrightarrow \alpha + \beta = \pi n,0 < \alpha + \beta < \pi;
$$
there ares no solutions. If $\alpha,\beta \color{red}\le \pi/2$, then $\alpha + \beta = \pi$.

In the second case,
$$\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} = \cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \Longrightarrow 2\sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2 = 0,
$$
and $\alpha=2\pi k$ or $\beta=2\pi m$, $k,m\in\mathbb Z$.

Anyway, your statement is false.

Answer (score 2):

We have -

> $\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta)$

$\implies \sin\alpha\cos\beta+cos\alpha\sin\beta=\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\beta$

$\implies\displaystyle\sin\alpha(\cos\beta-\sin\alpha)+\sin\beta(\cos\alpha-\sin\beta)=0$

$\implies2 \sin\alpha\cdot \sin\left({\frac{\beta+\frac \pi2-\alpha}{2}}\right)\cdot \sin\left({\frac {\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha-\beta}{2}}\right)+2\sin\beta\cdot \sin\left({\frac{\alpha+\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta}{2}}\right)\cdot \sin\left({\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta-\alpha}{2}}\right)=0$

$\implies\sin\alpha\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)+\sin\beta\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)=0$

$\implies\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\beta+\alpha}{2}\right)=0$

$\implies\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}=0$

$\implies \alpha+\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Equation $(2)$ says that
$$\sin\alpha(\sin\alpha-\cos\beta)=\sin\beta(\cos\alpha-\sin\beta)\ .$$
With $\beta:={\pi\over2}-\beta'$ we therefore have
$$\sin\alpha(\sin\alpha-\sin\beta')=\sin\beta(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta')\ .$$
When $\alpha\ne\beta'$ the two sides of the last equation have different signs.

Answer (score 0):

Its given (by you) that ${sin}^2\alpha+{sin}^2\beta={sin}(\alpha+\beta) ..........eqn (1)$

But ${sin}^2\beta=1-{cos}^2\beta$

Slotting the identity into $eqn(1)$ gives: $${sin}^2\alpha+(1-{cos}^2\beta)={sin}(\alpha+\beta) $$
$$1-({cos}^2\beta-{sin}^2\alpha)={sin}(\alpha+\beta)$$
$$1-{cos}(\alpha+\beta)={sin}(\alpha+\beta)$$
$${sin}(\alpha+\beta)+{cos}(\alpha+\beta)=1$$
Let $(\alpha+\beta)=A$ Therefore $sinA+cosA=1$

Solving this further by squaring both sides gives:
$${sin}^2A+{cos}^2A+2sinAcosA=1$$
$$2sinAcosA=0$$
Therefore $sinA=0$ or $cos A=0$

This gives $A=0$ or $A=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Recall that $(\alpha+\beta)=A$

Therefore $\alpha+\beta=0$ or $\alpha+\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: How $\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\alpha=\cos(\alpha+\beta)?$

Comment: I too have the same query- How $\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\alpha=\cos(\alpha+\beta)?$

Comment: Oops, sorry folks. I think I made a fundamental error there. Let me resolve

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),

$$\sin^2A+\sin^2B=1-(\cos^2A-\sin^2B)=1-\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)$$

$$\implies\sin(A+B)+\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)=1$$

Using [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) for $\sin(A+B),\cos(A+B)$ and setting $\tan\dfrac{A+B}2=t,$

$$[1+\cos(A-B)]t^2-2t+1-\cos(A-B)=0$$

Using Weierstrass substitution for $\cos(A-B),$

$$t=1,\tan^2\dfrac{A-B}2$$

If $\tan\dfrac{A+B}2=1,\dfrac{A+B}2=n\pi+\dfrac\pi2\iff A+B=?$ where $n$

But I'm not sure about  $\tan\dfrac{A+B}2=\tan^2\dfrac{A-B}2$