# Finding conditional extrema with trig functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Find the conditional extrema of $$f(x,y)=\cos^2x+\cos^2y,\quad g(x,y)=x-y+\frac{\pi}{4}=0.$$

I have a problem with finding a solution to this problem. Using Lagrange multipliers i come up with a system of three equations which i don't know how to solve:
\begin{align}
F_x &=-2\sin x\cos x+1=0\\
F_y &=-2\sin y\cos y-1=0\\
F_\lambda &=x-y+\frac{\pi}{4}=0
\end{align}

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first two equations are missing a $\lambda$. After the fix, you will be looking at $-\sin 2x=-\lambda$, $-\sin 2y=\lambda$. After dealing with the special case $\lambda=0$, you get $\sin 2x=-\sin 2y$.  So $2x$ and $2y$ are close relatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your $F_x$ and $F_y$ are wrong. Since $$F(x,y,\lambda) = \cos^2 x + \cos^2 y +\lambda (x-y+\frac\pi4)$$

Derivatives should be $$F_x=-2\cos x \sin x + \lambda\\ F_y = -2\cos y \sin y - \lambda$$

Then, I suggest you sum the first two equations ($F_x=0$ and $F_y=0$).

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

W/O using calculus,

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),

$$\cos^2x+\cos^2y=\cdots=1+\cos(x-y)\cos(x+y)=1+\cos\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)\cos\left(y-\dfrac\pi4+y\right)$$