# Solve the equation: $\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(2x)+\cos^2(3x)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to solve the equation

> $$\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(2x)+\cos^2(3x)=1$$

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Use the addition angle formulae for the sine and cosine functions.

Comment: Hint: If you know the complex form $2cos(a) = z+\frac{1}{z}$ where $z=e^{ia}$ then you get the polynomial equation $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6=-z^3$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Can you suggest a solution for this question? Because I saw your answers from other posts are quite good

Comment: @Mathxx Thank you for your compliment!  That made my day!  Happy Holidays! - Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(2x)+\cos^2(3x)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$1+6\cos^2(x)-20\cos^4(x)+16\cos^6(x)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $y=\cos^2(x)$:

---

$$16y^3-20y^2+6y=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2y(2y-1)(4y-3)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(2y-1)(4y-3)=0$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Simplify $1+6\cos^2(x)-20\cos^4(x)+16\cos^6(x)=1$ and then substitute $y=\cos^2(x)$ and then you will get $16y^3-20y^2+6y+1=1$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(2x)+\cos^2(3x)=1$$
$$\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(3x)=1-\cos^2(2x)$$
$$\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(3x)=(1-\cos(2x))(1+\cos(2x))$$
$$\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(3x)=(2\sin^2(x))(2\cos^2(x))$$
$$\cos^2(x)+(4\cos^3(x)-3\cos (x))^2=2(1-\cos^2(x))(2\cos^2(x))$$
$$16\cos^6x-20\cos^4x+6\cos^2x=0$$
now, let $\cos^2 x=t$, $$8t^2-10t+3t=0$$
$$t(2t-1)(4t-3)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),

$$\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(2x)+\cos^2(3x)-1$$
$$=\cos^2(x)-\sin^23x+\cos^2(2x)$$
$$=\cos(3x-x)\cos(3x+x)+\cos^2(2x)$$
$$=\cos2x(\cos4x+\cos2x)$$

Now use [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) on $$\cos4x+\cos2x$$

Should I use a single word more?

---

Alternatively using $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1,$

$$\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(2x)+\cos^2(3x)=1$$

$$\iff\cos2x+\cos4x+\cos6x+1=0$$

$$\cos6x=2\cos^23x-1$$ and use Prosthaphaeresis Formula on $$\cos2x+\cos4x$$

Answer (score 0):

$\cos^2(x)+[2 \cos^2x-1]^2 +[4 \cos^3 x-3 \cos x]^2 = 1$, Simplify the equation to get: $ \cos^2 x [8 \cos^4 x - 10 \cos^2 x + 3] = 0$. Hope this will help.