# If $A+B+C=π$, prove that

Tags: trigonometry

> If $A+B+C=π$, prove that
>   $$\cos^2A+\cos^2B-\cos^2C=-2\cos A\cdot\cos B\cdot\cos C.$$

ATTEMPT:
Given $$A+B+C=π,$$
$$A+B=π-C$$
Taking "cos" on both sides 
$$\cos(A+B)=-\cos C.$$

Now, 
\begin{align*}
L.H.S&=\cos^2A+\cos^2B-\cos^2C\\
&=\frac{1+\cos 2A}{2}+\frac{1+\cos 2B}{2}-\cos^2 C\\
&=\frac{2+\cos 2A+\cos 2B}{2}-\cos^2C.
\end{align*}

How should I complete now?

Comment: Let  $A=0$, $B=0$, $C=π$. Then, $$\cos^2A+\cos^2B-\cos^2C=1+1-(-1)=3 \neq 2 = -2\cos A\cdot\cos B\cdot\cos C$$

Comment: Hint . Let $A=(m+d)/2$ and $ B=(m-d)/2.$ For the RHS, note that $\cos A \cos B=(1/2) (\cos (A+B)+\cos (A-B))=(1/2)(\cos 2 m+\cos 2 d).$

Comment: the question is wrong once I used Wolfram expands polynomials.

Comment: The statement as given is false. It's a near miss of this identity $$1 -\cos^2 A - \cos^2 B - \cos^2 C-2\cos A\cos B\cos C= 0$$

Comment: Changing the $\cos^2C$ on the left-hand side to $\sin^2C$ gives a valid identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity

> $$1 - \cos^2 A - \cos^2 B - \cos^2 C - 2 \cos A \cos B \cos C = 0$$

can be seen as a re-writing of the relation $\cos C = - \cos(A+B)$ without sines of $A$ and $B$:

$$\cos C = - \cos(A+B) = \sin A \sin B - \cos A \cos B$$
$$\cos C + \cos A \cos B = \sin A \sin B$$
$$\left(\;\cos C + \cos A \cos B\;\right)^2 = \sin^2 A \sin^2 B = \left(1-\cos^2 A\right)\left(1-\cos^2 B\right)$$
$$\cos^2 C + 2 \cos A \cos B \cos C \color{red}{+ \cos^2A \cos^2 B} = 1 - \cos^2 A - \cos^2 B \color{red}{+ \cos^2 A \cos^2 B}$$
and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

I edited to prove
$$1 -\cos^2 A - \cos^2 B - \cos^2 C-2\cos A\cos B\cos C= 0$$

I believe you need cosine law. Let a, b, c be respective sides of angle A, B, and C, then
$$-cos C = \frac{c^2 - a^2 - b^2}{2ab} $$
$$-cos B = \frac{b^2 - a^2 - c^2}{2ac} $$
$$-cos A = \frac{a^2 - b^2 - c^2}{2bc} $$

so we have
$$cosA cosB cos C = -\frac{(c^2 - a^2 - b^2)(b^2 - a^2 - c^2)(a^2 - b^2 - c^2)}{8(abc)^2}$$
$$1 -cos^2 C - cos^2 A - cos^2 B = -\frac{4(abc)^2 -c^2(c^2 - a^2 - b^2)^2 - b^2(b^2 - a^2 - c^2)^2 - a^2(a^2 - b^2 - c^2)^2}{4(abc)^2}$$

To provde original identity, we just need to prove:
$$4(abc)^2 -c^2(c^2 - a^2 - b^2)^2 - b^2(b^2 - a^2 - c^2)^2 - a^2(a^2 - b^2 - c^2)^2 = -(c^2 - a^2 - b^2)(b^2 - a^2 - c^2)(a^2 - b^2 - c^2)$$

Expand both side should verify the identity (From Wolfram, identity holds)

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely something wrong with the identity as you have entered it.  First, as user Konstantinos Kanak0glou has noted in the comments, the identity fails to hold for $A=B=0$ and $C=\pi$.

A second piece of evidence that the "identity" is false is that the condition $A+B+C=\pi$ is symmetric in the three variables, as is the RHS of the purported identity, but the LHS is not.

Answer (score 0):

$2\cos A\cos B\cos C$

$=\{\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)\}\cos C$

$=\cos(A-B)\{-\cos(A+B)\}-\cos^2C$ as $\cos(A+B)=\cos(\pi-C)=-\cos C$

$=-(\cos^2A-\sin^2B)-\cos^2C$ using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b)

$\implies2\cos A\cos B\cos C=1-(\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C)$