# Let $\alpha$ be such that $0\leq\alpha\leq\pi$.If $f(x)=\cos x+\cos(x+\alpha)+\cos(x+2\alpha)$ takes some constant number $c$ for any $x\in R$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\alpha$ be a real number such that $0\leq\alpha\leq\pi$.If $f(x)=\cos x+\cos(x+\alpha)+\cos(x+2\alpha)$ takes some constant number $c$ for any $x\in R$,then find the value of $\lfloor c+\alpha \rfloor$.

---

I simplified $f(x)=\cos x+\cos(x+\alpha)+\cos(x+2\alpha)=\cos(x+\alpha)(2\cos\alpha+1)$
If $f(x)$ takes the value $c$,then $f(x)=\cos(x+\alpha)(2\cos\alpha+1)=c$
I do not know how to solve it further.

Comment: Is the answer 3 ?

Comment: Answer given is $2$

Comment: Yeah I got it I had made a silly mistake, $\alpha ={ {2\pi} \over 3}$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679646/find-all-a-b-such-that-y-cos2-x-cos2-xa-2-cos-x-cos-xa-cos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this equation is true for all $x$ we can substitute values and see what we get. Substitute $\pi$ and $0$.

Equation 1: $c = 1 + cos(\alpha) + cos(2\alpha)$

Equation 2: $c = -1 - cos(\alpha) - cos(2\alpha)$

Using these two we get $c=0$

$cos(\alpha) = {{-1}\over 2}$

$\Rightarrow \alpha = {{2\pi}\over 3}$

Answer (score 2):

$\text{cos}(x+\alpha)$ is obviously non-constant. $2\text{cos}(\alpha)+1$ is obviously constant. The product of a constant and a non-constant function is always non-constant, except if this constant is zero (because...)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Look at the expression for $x\mapsto f(x)$ you have obtained. Under what circumstances can it be constant? Your findings will then determine $c$ and $\alpha$.