# Trigonometry problem ( Restricted variables)

Tags: trigonometry

I want to prove that if $x+y = z$ , then

$$\cos^2 x + \cos^2 y + \cos^2 z - 2\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z) = 1.$$

I have tried this question by putting z = x+y in the equation , but still there are a  lot of terms left at the end ...

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos^2 x + \cos^2 y + \cos^2 z - 2\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z) = $$
$$=\frac32+\frac{\cos 2x+\cos 2y+\cos 2z}{2}-2\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z)=$$
$$=\frac32+\frac{\cos 2x+\cos 2y}{2}+\frac{\cos 2z}{2}-2\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z)=$$
$$=\frac32+\cos (x+y)\cos(x-y)+\frac{2\cos^2 z-1}2-2\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z)=$$
$$=1+\cos z\left(\cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)-2\cos(x)\cos(y)\right)=$$
$$=1+\cos z \left(2\cos x \cos y-2 \cos x \cos y\right)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  & {{\cos }^{2}}z={{\cos }^{2}}(x+y)={{\left( \cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y \right)}^{2}} \\ 
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,={{\cos }^{2}}x{{\cos }^{2}}y-\sin 2x\sin 2y+{{\sin }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y \\ 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
  & 2\cos x\cos y\cos z=2\cos x\cos y\cos (x+y) \\ 
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=2\cos x\cos y(\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y) \\ 
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=2{{\cos }^{2}}x{{\cos }^{2}}y-\sin 2x\sin 2y \\ 
\end{align}
we have
[\begin{align}
  & I={{\cos }^{2}}x+{{\cos }^{2}}y+{{\cos }^{2}}z-2\cos x\cos y\cos z \\ 
 & \,\,\,={{\cos }^{2}}x+{{\cos }^{2}}y+\underline{{{\cos }^{2}}x{{\cos }^{2}}y}-\sin 2x\sin 2y+{{\sin }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y\underline{-2{{\cos }^{2}}x{{\cos }^{2}}y}+\sin 2x\sin 2y \\ 
 & \,\,\,={{\cos }^{2}}x+{{\cos }^{2}}y+{{\sin }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y-{{\cos }^{2}}x{{\cos }^{2}}y \\ 
 & \,\,\,={{\cos }^{2}}x-{{\cos }^{2}}x{{\cos }^{2}}y+{{\cos }^{2}}y+{{\sin }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y \\ 
 & \,\,\,={{\cos }^{2}}x(1-{{\cos }^{2}}y)+{{\cos }^{2}}y+{{\sin }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y \\ 
 & \,\,\,={{\cos }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y+{{\cos }^{2}}y+{{\sin }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y \\ 
 & \,\,\,=({{\cos }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y+{{\sin }^{2}}x{{\sin }^{2}}y)+{{\cos }^{2}}y \\ 
 & \,\,\,={{\sin }^{2}}y\underbrace{({{\cos }^{2}}x+{{\sin }^{2}}x)}_{1}+{{\cos }^{2}}y \\ 
 & \,\,\,={{\sin }^{2}}y+{{\cos }^{2}}y \\ 
 & \,\,\,=\,1 \\ 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),

$$F=\cos^2x+\cos^2y+\cos^2z=1+\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)+\cos z\cdot\cos z$$

If $\cos(x+y)=\cos z\iff x+y=2m\pi\pm z$ where $m$ is any integer

$$F=1+\cos z\cos(x-y)+\cos z\cos(x+y)=1+\cos z[\cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)]=?$$