# Trigonometric Conditional Identities

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that if $x+y = z$ , then $\cos^2x + \cos^2y + \cos^2z - 2\cos x.\cos y.\cos z = \cos(x+y - z)$.
My work: I tried to solve by converting the cos squared term into double angle form and transforming the product$- \cos x.\cos y$ into sum form. But not able to get the result.

Comment: If $x+y = z$, then $\cos (x+y-z)$ is just $1$. Why not write that instead?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Using  [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),

$$\cos^2x+\cos^2y=\cdots=1+\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)$$

Now if $\cos(x+y)=\cos z\iff x+y=2m\pi\pm z$ where $m$ is any integer