# Finding maximum of discrete function

Tags: trigonometry, discrete-optimization, maxima-minima

I have a following function:

$f(x)=sin^2(a\cdot x)+sin^2(a\cdot (b-x))$

where $0\leq x \leq b$, $0<a\cdot b<\pi/2$, and $3\pi/2<a\cdot b<2\pi$. By exhaustive search I have noticed that function is strictly convex on the given range and that it has one extrema at $b/2$ which is a minimum while maximum is correspondingly attained at borders of the function ($0$ and b). My problem is that the function is discrete so I can not use the first and the second derivative for finding the minimum and maximum. Does anyone has any idea how to prove that my maximum is achieved at borders?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Could you expand you answer a little bit?

Comment: I was planning to use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Colud you write the full answer pls.