# Given $A+B=135^\circ$ ,i have to find range of values of $\sin^2A+\sin^2B$

Tags: trigonometry

Given in a triangle $ABC$, $A+B=135^\circ$ ,i have to find value of $\sin^2A+\sin^2B$

**ATTEMPT**

i write as

$\sin^2A+\sin^2(135^\circ-A)$

$\sin^2A+\sin^2(45+A)$

$1-cos^2(A)+\sin^2(45+A)$

$1 - (cos(45+2A)(cos45))$

$1- \frac{1}{\sqrt2}cos(45+2A)$

Now  $0 <A< 135$\

$0 <2A< 270$

$45 <2A+45< 315$

$\cos45 <cos(2A+45)< \cos315$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt2} <cos(2A+45)< \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

I am stuck here as to where i have gone wrong

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think there is going to be only one value?

Comment: Okay mention that you are looking for inequality in the question.

Comment: What you are doing in fourth step?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh using $cos^2a-sin^2b=cos(a+b)cos(a-b)$

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your
$$Q=1-{1\over\sqrt{2}}\cos\left(2A+{\pi\over4}\right)$$
is correct. But in the formulation of the problem there were no further restrictions on $A$ and $B$. If $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be angles of a triangle then $0<A<{3\pi\over4}$, and $\phi:=2A+{\pi\over4}$ satisfies ${\pi\over4}<\phi<{7\pi\over4}$, hence $-1\leq\cos\phi<{1\over\sqrt{2}}$. (Look at the graph of $\cos$ in the interval ${\pi\over4}<\phi<{7\pi\over4}$.) It follows that $Q=1-{1\over\sqrt{2}}\cos\phi$ satisfies
$${1\over2}<Q\leq1+{1\over\sqrt{2}}\ .$$
Your line $\cos45^\circ <\cos(2A+45^\circ)< \cos315^\circ$ is wrong.

Comment: Sir, in the question it is given that A,B are angles of a triangle ABC

Comment: @TaylorTed, There is no information in your  question that $A,B$ are angles of a triangle.

Comment: Yes sorry my bad, i will edit it

Comment: @Christian Blatter Why i cannot take cosine in inequality $pi/4<phi<7pi/4$

Comment: i mean after finding phi , how are you finding cos phi

Comment: @TaylorTed You can't take cosine of the inequality because cosine isn't an increasing function. Sometimes it goes up, sometimes it goes down. Example where it fails: $$\frac\pi4 < \frac\pi2$$ but $$\cos(\frac\pi4)>\cos(\frac\pi2)$$

Answer (score 1):

So you have
$\sin^2A+\sin^2(135^\circ-A)=\sin^2A+\sin^2(45+A)$
At maximum and minimum values of this expression, we have

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}A}(\sin^2A+\sin^2(45^{\circ}+A))=0$$
$$2\sin(A)\cos(A)+2\sin(A+45^{\circ})\cos(A+45^{\circ})=0$$
$$\sin(2A)+\sin(2A+90^{\circ})=0$$
$$\sin(2A)+\cos(2A)=0$$
$$\sqrt{2}\sin(2A + 45^{\circ}) =0$$
...

Comment: I don't know about differentiation. btw what is wrong with my solution

Comment: You are using the inequality of domain to indicate directly the inequality of the image

Comment: @ZelosMalum ok thanks i see it