# How can I prove this trigonometric equation with squares of sines?

Tags: trigonometry

Here is the equation:

$$\sin^2(a+b)+\sin^2(a-b)=1-\cos(2a)\cos(2b)$$

Following from comment help,

$${\left(\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b\right)}^2 + {\left(\sin a \cos b - \cos a \sin b\right)}^2$$

$$=\sin^2 a \cos^2b + \cos^2 a \sin^2 b + \sin^2 a \cos^2 b + \cos^2 a \sin^2 b$$

I am stuck here, how do I proceed **from here?**

**Edit:** from answers I understand how to prove,but how to prove from where I am stuck?

Comment: Use the formulas for $\sin(x\pm y)$ and $\cos(2x)$ (look them up) and check that the two sides are equal.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli trying

Comment: Post your attempt. And also, don't post images of equations, use mathjax. Really, as a long time user, you shoud know better than to post a low quality question like this.

Comment: The last passage is wrong: $\sin^2a+\sin^2b\ne1$

Comment: @5xum edited :) now is it still worthy to close as off topic? _I can see 3 close votes_

Comment: Well *now* it's not a closable question, of course. I retracted my vote, and the others will too, probably.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, let's the start the manipulation at the left hand side. Using the identity
$$\sin^2\theta=\frac{1-\cos 2\theta}{2}$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sin^2(a+b)+\sin^2(a-b)&=\frac{1-\cos(2a+2b)}{2}+\frac{1-\cos(2a-2b)}{2}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\cos(2a+2b)+\cos(2a-2b)\bigg]\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2}\bigg[(\cos 2a\cos 2b-\sin 2a\sin 2b)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad +(\cos 2a\cos 2b+\sin 2a\sin 2b)\bigg]\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2}\bigg[2\cos 2a\cos 2b\bigg]\\
&=1-\cos 2a\cos 2b.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CEU3Q.jpg

Comment: @Fawad What is the problem? why you paste that image?

Comment: Your answer has [mathjax problem](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13747/what-should-we-do-about-really-long-mathjax) don't know if it could be improved,it would be better.

Comment: @Fawad Ah okay, nice pointing out the error. I will fix it and please take a review if it is already okay.

Comment: @Fawad Done editing. Is it already okay?

Comment: Yep,nice clean and fine.

Answer (score 6):

On the LHS, you have $$2s_a^2c_b^2+2c_a^2s_b^2$$ after grouping.

On the RHS,

$$1-(c_a^2-s_a^2)(c_b^2-s_b^2)=(c_a^2+s_a^2)(c_b^2+s_b^2)-(c_a^2-s_a^2)(c_b^2-s_b^2)=2s_a^2c_b^2+2c_a^2s_b^2.$$

Comment: Got,thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

On RHS we have,
$$
1-\cos(2a)\cos(2b) = 1-\cos^2a\cos^2b+\cos^2a\sin^2b+\sin^2a\cos^2b-\sin^2a\sin^2b
= (\cos^2a\sin^2b+\sin^2a\cos^2b)+1-\cos^2a+\sin^b\cos^2a-\sin^2a\sin^2b
= (\cos^2a\sin^2b+\sin^2a\cos^2b)+\sin^2b\cos^2a+\sin^2a-\sin^2a\sin^2b
= 2(\cos^2a\sin^2b+\sin^2a\cos^2b)
= LHS
$$ 
Hence proved

Comment: Try using, *e.g.*, `$\cos x$` for $\cos x$ instead of `$cos x$` for $cos x$.

Comment: @Shaun edit done

Comment: @Shaun, thanks for guiding me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

We have $$
\begin{align}
\sin^2(a+b)+\sin^2(a-b)&=\frac{1-\cos(2(a+b))}{2}+\frac{1-\cos(2(a-b))}{2}\\
&=1-\frac{\color{red}{\cos(2a+2b)}+\color{blue}{\cos(2a-2b)}}{2}\\
&=1-\frac{\color{red}{\cos 2a\cos 2b-\sin 2a\sin 2b}+ \color{blue}{\cos 2a\cos 2b+\sin 2a\sin 2b}}{2}\\
&=1-\frac{2\cos 2a\cos 2b}{2}\\
&=1-\cos 2a\cos 2b.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b) on

$$\sin^2(A+B)+\sin^2(A-B)=1-\{\cos^2(A+B)-\sin^2(A-B)\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Other approach: let $u=a+b,v=a-b$.

Then

$$\begin{align}\cos(u+v)\cos(u-v)&=(\cos u\cos v-\sin u\sin v)\cdot(\cos u\cos v+\sin u\sin v)\\
&=\cos^2u\cos^2v-\sin^2u\sin^2v\\
&=(1-\sin^2u)(1-\sin^2v)-\sin^2u\sin^2v\\
&=1-\sin^2u-\sin^2v.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Given that
$$ \cos(u) = \frac{e^{iu} + e^{-iu}}{2} , \sin(u) = \frac{e^{iu} - e^{-iu}}{2i} \text{ , and } e^{2u}+ e^{-2u} = \left(e^{u} - e^{-u}\right)^2 + 2,$$

we prove the identity by

$$\begin{align} 1 - \cos(2a) \cos(2b) & = 1 - \frac{ \left( e^{2ia} + e^{-2ia} \right) \left(e^{2ib} + e^{-2ib} \right)}{4}\\
& = \frac{e^{2i(a + b)} + e^{-2i(a + b)} + e^{2i(a - b)} + e^{-2i(a - b)} - 4}{-4}\\
& = \frac{ \left( e^{i(a + b)} - e^{-i(a + b)} \right)^2  + 2 + \left( e^{i(a - b)} - e^{-i(a - b)} \right)^2 + 2 - 4}{4i^2} \\
& = \sin^2(a+b) + \sin^2(a - b)\end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^2(a+b)+\sin^2(a−b)
$

$=\sin^2a\cos^2b+\cos^2a\sin^2b+\sin^2a\cos^2b+\cos^2a\sin^2b
$

$=2(\sin^2a\cos^2b+\cos^2a\sin^2b)
$

$=2\left ({\left (\dfrac{(1-\cos(2a)}{2}\right )(\cos^2b)+\left (\dfrac{\cos(2a)+1}{2}\right )(\sin^2b)}\right )
$

$=1+\cos(2a)\sin^2b-\cos(2a)\cos^2b
$

$=1-\cos(2a)\cos(2b)
$

Hence proved.