# Prove that: $\cos 4A-\cos 4B=8(\cos A-\cos B)(\cos A + \cos B)(\cos A - \sin B)(\cos A + \sin B)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove that: $\cos 4A-\cos 4B=8(\cos A-\cos B)(\cos A + \cos B)(\cos A - \sin B)(\cos A + \sin B)$

My Attempt:

$$L.H.S=\cos 4A - \cos 4B$$
$$=2\sin \dfrac {4A+4B}{2}.\sin \dfrac {4B-4A}{2}$$
$$=2\sin (2A+2B).\sin (2B-2A)$$
How do I proceed further?

Comment: RHS = $8(\cos^{2} A - \cos^{2} B)(\cos^{2} A - \sin^{2} B)$. Also use $\sin 2 A = 2\sin \cos A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start on the right:
\begin{align} 
&8(\cos{A}-\cos{B})(\cos{A}+\cos{B})(\cos{A}-\sin{B})(\cos{A}+\sin{B}) \\
&= 2(2\cos^2{A}-2\cos^2{B})(2\cos^2{A}-2\sin^2{B}) \\
&= 2(\cos{2A}-\cos{2B})(\cos{2A}+\cos{2B}) \\
&=  2\cos^2{2A}-2\cos^2{2B} \\
&= \cos{4A}-\cos{4B},
\end{align}
using $\cos{2\theta}=2\cos^2{\theta}-1=1-2\sin^2{\theta}$ liberally.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

From the RHS,

use  [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b)

and by  [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b),

$$\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B=1-\cos^2A-(1-\cos^2B)$$

Can you take it from here?