# How to prove that $1/\sin^2x + 1/\sin^2y - 2\cos(x-y)/(\sin x\sin y) = \sin^2(x-y)/(\sin^2x\sin^2y)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

How to prove that -

$$\frac 1{\sin^2x} + \frac 1 {\sin^2y} - \frac{2\cos(x-y)}{\sin x\sin y} = \frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{\sin^2x\sin^2y}$$

Comment: Does putting it all over a denominator of $\sin^2x\sin^2y$ and then simplifying the numerator not work?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown nope :(

Comment: You see, if that really doesn't work then the statement won't be true $\frown$.

Comment: i think this Statement is true, if the denominators are not equal zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator $$=\sin^2x+\sin^2y-\cos(x-y)\cdot2\sin x\sin y$$

$$=\sin^2x+\sin^2y-\cos(x-y)[\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)]$$

$$=\sin^2x+\sin^2y-\cos^2(x-y)+\cos(x-y)\cos(x+y)$$

Now use [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b)

Answer (score 0):

we have (the left-hand-side)
$$\frac{\sin(x)^2+\sin(y)^2-2(\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y))\sin(x)\sin(y)}{\sin(x)^2\sin(y)^2}$$ and this must be equal $$\frac{\sin(x)^2\cos(y)^2+\cos(x)^2\sin(y)^2-2\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(y)\cos(y)}{\sin(x)^2\sin(y)^2}$$ now we will write only the numerators:
both Terms are equal since
$$2\sin(x)^2\sin(y)^2-2\left(\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)\right)\sin(x)\sin(y)=$$
$$-2\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(y)\cos(y)$$