# Trigonometry terms in GP and their values

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

[image: Question:]

Question: 
If `tan((π/12) - x), tan (π/12), tan((π/12) + x)` in the order are the three consecutive terms of a GP then sum all the solutions in [0,314] is kπ. Find value of k.

Attempt:
I tried assuming `a = tan (π/12) and y = tanx` to make my calculations easier. 
`a^2 = (a+y)/(1-ay) * (a-y)/(1+ay)`

Simplifying this simple removes y from the expression. What should I do?
Where am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write tan as $\dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$ like

$$\dfrac{\sin\pi/12\cos(\pi/12-x)}{\cos\pi/12\sin(\pi/12-x)}=?$$

Now apply componendo & dividendo(https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/)

Comment: ?? I couldn't reach to this expression. Wasn't it simple manipulations?

Comment: @Khizir, If $a,b,c$ are in GP $$b/a=c/b $$ Now as already mentioned please write tan as $\sin/\cos$

Comment: Yes, I know this thing, but taking it as sin/cos doesn't bring up this expression for me.

Comment: @Khizir, Please share your progress

Comment: Okay okay I get that... I was using b^2 = a*c. I thought finally we will have to solve it, why not directly use it... Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Writing like $b^2=ca,$

$$\dfrac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}=\dfrac{\sin(A-x)\sin(A+x)}{\cos(A-x)\cos(A+x)}$$

Now use [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b)

and

[Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b)

Then
https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/

Finally double formula for cosine.

Please let me know if you face any further problem?