# Find value of $|z_2+z_3|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given that complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ lie on unit circle and

$$|z_1-z_2|^2+|z_1-z_3|^2=4$$ Then find value of $|z_2+z_3|$

My try:

We can take $z_1=e^{i\alpha}$, $z_2=e^{i\beta}$ and $z_3=e^{i\gamma}$

So we have

$$|z_1-z_2|=2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)$$

$$|z_1-z_3|=2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right)$$

So we get:

$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right)=1$$

Now we have:

$$|z_2+z_3|=2\cos\left(\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)$$

Any help here?

Comment: I modified the answer, taking into account a comment pointing out to me that once $z_1$ and $z_2$ are fixed, there are in fact two choices for $z_3$...

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comment by [Stancek](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/109322/tstancek), whom I thank, my previous answer was not correct since it only reported *one* solution, that was indenpendent on the choice of $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$, i.e 
$$|z_2+z_3|=0,$$
easily found by Pythagorean Theorem.

The general solution can be determined as follows. Use the fact that $|z|^2 = zz^*$, to re-write the equation in the form
$$|z_1|^2 - 2\Re\{z_1z_2^*\} + |z_2|^2 + |z_1|^2 - 2\Re\{z_1z_3^*\} + |z_3|^2=4.$$
Since the points lie on the unit circle, the equation then simplifies to
$$ \Re\{z_1z_2^*\} = -\Re\{z_1z_3^*\}.$$
If you set $z_1 = 1$ you get
$$\Re\{z_2\} = -\Re\{z_3\}.$$
Which yields the *two solutions*
$$z_3 = -z_2$$
and
$$z_3 = -z_2^*.$$
The first solution leads to 
$$\boxed{|z_2+z_3|=0},$$
that is to $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ being vertices of a right-angled triangle. 
The second one, in the case $z_1=1$ can be expressed as 
$$|z_2+z_3|= 2\left|\Im\{z_2\}\right|.$$
Taking into account the arbitray phase of $z_1$ yields
$$\boxed{|z_2+z_3|= 2\left|\Im \left\{z_1z_2^*\right\}\right|}.$$
[image]

Comment: I think that it is not always 0. Because if you fix points $z_1$ and $z_2$, there are two choices for $z_3$. One is opposite to $z_2$, but the other one is not.

Comment: @TStancek thanks. I'll double check and correct as soon as possible

Comment: @TStancek check out the changes if you like. Now it should be correct, I hope. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure. I think you should probably multiply all $z_1,z_2$ and $z_3$ by $z_1^{-1}$ to move the starting position of points to that special position where  $z_1 = 1$, than do the complex conjugation of opposite point and only than multiply it back by $z_1$. So actually I think the second $z_3$ should be equal to $\overline{-(z_2\cdot z_1^{-1})} \cdot z_1$. But I am really not sure and currently dont have time to verify this.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $|z|=1$, then $\overline{z}=1/z$. Thus for $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ on the unit circle, we have

$$\begin{align}
|z_1-z_2|^2+|z_1-z_3|^2
&=\left(z_1-z_2\right)\left({1\over z_1}-{1\over z_2}\right)+\left(z_1-z_3\right)\left({1\over z_1}-{1\over z_3}\right)\\
&=4-\left({z_1\over z_2}+{z_2\over z_1}+{z_1\over z_3}+{z_3\over z_1} \right)\\
&=4-\left((z_1^2+z_2z_3)(z_2+z_3)\over z_1z_2z_3 \right)
\end{align}$$

It follows that $|z_1-z_2|^2+|z_1-z_3|^2=4$ if and only if $(z_1^2+z_2z_3)(z_2+z_3)=0$.  Since we can always arrange for $z_1^2=-z_2z_3$ on the unit circle, $|z_2+z_3|$ can take any value between $0$ and $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Writing $$\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}=\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}+\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}$$ and combing this with trigonometric identity for the sum of cosine $$\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$$ we get
\begin{align}\cos\left(\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2}\right)&=\cos\left(\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}+\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right)\\
&=\cos\left(\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\right)\cdot\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right).\end{align}
Now rewrite the identity
$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right)=1$$
as
$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)=1-\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right)=\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}\right),$$
and plug this into the previous to conclude.

Comment: Using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b,

$$0=\cos^2\dfrac{\alpha-\gamma}2-\sin^2\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}2=\cos\dfrac{\beta-\gamma}2\cos\dfrac{2\alpha-\beta-\gamma}2$$