# Eliminating $\theta$ from the system $x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta=-\sin4\theta$, $x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=\frac52-\frac32\cos4\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> Eliminate $\theta$ from the system of equations.
>   $$\begin{align}
> x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta&=\phantom{\frac52\frac32}-\sin4\theta \\
> x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta&=\frac52-\frac32\cos4\theta
> \end{align}$$

I am stuck at this question after squaring and adding.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: You're a member of this site already 5 months, and you've asked 6 questions. It's about time to learn how to write mathematics correctly here.

Comment: And I can{t see a clear, more or less easy way to eliminate $\;\theta\;$ . You can solve for $\;x\;$ and $\;y\;$ as functions of theta, though.

Comment: We may substitute $( x=r \cos  \theta, y= r \sin \theta ) $ it helps, Right?

Answer (score 2):

This question, like your [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3213254/409), seems almost cruel. There don't seem to be *particularly* elegant ways to proceed, and the solutions aren't *particularly* pretty. (Who's inflicting these problems on you?)

In these situations, I often just convert to complex exponentials, via 
$$\cos u = \frac12\left(e^{iu}+e^{-iu}\right) \qquad \sin u = \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iu}-e^{-iu}\right)$$
and let *Mathematica* do all the symbol-crunching.

Here, defining $p := e^{i\theta}$, the equations become
$$\begin{align}
p^8 + \phantom{2}p^5 ( x - i y)\phantom{-10p^4\;\,} -\phantom{2} p^3 (x+iy) - 1 &= 0 \\
3 p^8 + 2 p^5 (x-iy) - 10 p^4  + 2 p^3 (x+iy) + 3 &= 0 
\end{align}$$

At this point, "all we need to do" is eliminate $p$. In a polynomial system, this can be accomplished using the [method of resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), conveniently implemented by *Mathematica*'s `Resultant` function (because no one should be applying this method by hand). The method yields this $\theta$-free relation:

$$\begin{align}
0 &= x^{10}+5 x^8 y^2+10 x^6 x^4 + 10 x^4 y^6+5 x^2 y^8+y^{10} \\
&-705 x^8+12180 x^6 y^2 -24230 x^4 y^4+12180 x^2 y^6-705 y^8 \\
&+122560 x^6-112320 x^4 y^2 -112320 x^2 y^4 +122560 y^6 \\
&+599040 x^4-1361920 x^2 y^2 +599040 y^4 \\
&+327680 x^2+327680 y^2 \\
&-1048576 
\end{align}$$

It happens that we can find a lot of $(x^2+y^2)$ groupings, and write, say,

> $$\begin{align}
> 0 &= \left(x^2 + y^2\right)^5 - 705 \left( x^2 + y^2\right)^4+122560\left(x^2+y^2\right)^3+599040\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2+327680\left(x^2+y^2\right)\\
> &+5000x^2y^2\left(3\left(x^2 + y^2\right)^2 -96 \left(x^2+y^2\right) -512 -10x^2y^2 \right) \\
> & -1048576 \\
> \end{align} \tag{$\star$}$$

Which is *marginally* better, I suppose. There may be additional clever groupings, but it hardly seems worth the trouble to look for them. (**Note:** I can't even guarantee that I transcribed everything properly.) Even so, I hope this helps. $\square$

---

**Addendum.** The appearance of complex conjugates in $(2)$ suggests that there may be some benefit in expressing things in terms of $z := x+iy$ and $\overline{z}:=x-iy$. It even helps to work towards this from the outset. Writing $(1)$ and $(2)$ for the original equations, we can obtain these conjugate equations:
$$\begin{align}
(1) + i(2): &\quad \phantom{5}p^8 - 10 p^4\phantom{z} + \phantom{1}4 p^3 z + 5  = 0 \\
(1) - i(2): &\quad 5 p^8 + \phantom{1}4 p^5 \overline{z} - 10 p^4\phantom{z} + 1 = 0 \\
\end{align}$$
The equations are a little nicer-looking, but they don't really make the task of eliminating $p$ any easier. A computer algebra system doesn't care anyway. Be that as it may, applying the method of resultants yields
$$\begin{align}
0 &= 16777216 - 5242880 z \overline{z} - 
 4464640 z^2 \overline{z}^2 - 1000960 z^3 \overline{z}^3 + 
 30 z^4 \overline{z}^4 - 16 z^5 \overline{z}^5 \\
&+2500\left(z^4+\overline{z}^4\right)(-1024-192z\overline{z}+z^2\overline{z}^2) \\
&+ 3125 \left(z^8 + \overline{z}^8\right)  
\end{align}$$
The powers of $z\overline{z}$ are nice to see, because they give us $x^2+y^2$. Also, we can manipulate the expression to include powers of $z^2+\overline{z}^2=2(x^2-y^2)$; doing so is surprisingly effective, as the left-over $z\overline{z}$ terms factor:
$$16 (z \overline{z}-16)^5 -3125 (z^2 + \overline{z}^2)^4 
+ 10000\left(z^2 + \overline{z}^2\right)^2 \left(256 + 48 z\overline{z} + z^2 \overline{z}^2\right)= 0$$ 
Abbreviating with $u:= z\overline{z}=x^2+y^2$ and $v:=\frac12(z^2+\overline{z}^2)=x^2-y^2$, this is

> $$(u-16)^5 + 2500 v^2\left(u^2+48u+256\right) - 3125 v^4 = 0 \tag{$\star\star$}$$

This might be *about* as good as things get.

Comment: This seems to be less severe :)

Comment: [Someone tamed this cruel problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4342525/1008807)

Answer (score 1):

My believe that one of the coefficients of $x,y$  in [Eliminating $\theta$ from trigonometric system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213198/eliminating-theta-from-trigonometric-system) will be negative has been corroborated by the current question.

Solving for $x,y$

$$\dfrac x{-\cos t(3\cos4t-5)-2\sin t\sin4t}=\dfrac y{2\cos t\sin4t-\sin t(3\cos4t-5)}=\dfrac12$$

$$4x=10\cos t-5\cos3t-\cos5t\iff x=5c-4c^5$$

$$4y=-\sin5t+5\sin3t+10\sin t\iff y=5s-4s^5$$  where $c=\cos t,s=\sin t$ using [this](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAnglesSine.htm) and [this](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAngles.htm#Formulae)

$$x^2+y^2=25-40(1-2c^2s^2)+16(1-3c^2s^2)$$

$$=1+32c^2s^2=1+8\sin^22t=1+4(1-\cos4t)=5-4\cos4t$$

$$\cos4t=\dfrac{5-x^2-y^2}4\ \ \ \  (1)$$

Again squaring & adding  $$4(x^2+y^2)=4\sin^24t+(5-3\cos4t)^2=25+4(1-\cos^24t)+9\cos^24t-30\cos4t\ \ \ \  (2)$$

Replace the value of $\cos4t$ in $(2)$ from $(1)$

Answer (score 0):

There is a catch,  a trap sort of. Posting nevertheless..

If we make change of variable by substituting $( x=r \cos  \theta, y= r \sin \theta ) $ it changes in a strange way.

$$ r (\sin \theta \cos \theta - \sin \theta \cos \theta)  = 0 = f(\theta),$$

$$ r( \sin ^2\theta +\cos^2 \theta ) = r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = g(\theta) = 5/2-3/2 \cos 4 \theta $$

The first equation says $r=0$ .

The second figure is a 4 leaved rose configured to be never  at the origin.

So problem is a designed contradiction..

$(x,y) $ are determinate or indeterminate constants including null solutions  or so it seems for now to me..

Comment: There's no reason that $\theta$ would be the same in the equations and the parameterization of $(x,y)$.

Comment: Do you mean  a change of variable cannot be allowed?

Comment: You can certainly write $(x,y)=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$. But assuming $\phi=\theta$ is unjustified; indeed, it leads to the contradiction you derived.