# Eliminate $\theta$ from $\sin3\theta=a\cos\theta$ and $\cos3\theta=b\sin\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Eliminate $\theta$ from $$\sin3\theta=a\cos\theta$$ $$\cos3\theta=b\sin\theta$$

I came to this point while trying to solve this problem: [Eliminating $\theta$ from trigonometric system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3213198/1003172) (Remark: Symbols differ from the original question)

We can find $$b+a=\frac{2\cos2\theta}{\sin2\theta}$$ $$b-a=\frac{2\cos4\theta}{\sin2\theta}$$

Though at the moment I can't imagine how to arrange these to get a proper relation between $a$ and $b$. We can replace $\sin$ and $\cos$ with $\tan$ and then proceed, but it is cumbersome.

I suspect that there should be a clever way to end this, giving a beautiful answer. For reference, like in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365325/1003172) question, a specific method gives the desired answer.$\leftarrow\small \text{(not strictly relevant)}$

So, what is the *happy ending* of this problem?

Comment: Hint: we have $\tan3\theta=\frac{a}{b}\cot\theta$ which, defining $t:=\tan\theta$, rearranges to a quadratic in $t^2$.

Comment: Another interesting equality is $\frac{a b -1}{2} = \cos 4 \theta$, and with the first of your  equalities produces a relation between $a$, $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBases%5B%20%7Bp%5E3%20-%203%20p%20q%5E2-%20b%20q%2C%203%20p%5E2%20q%20-%20q%5E3-%20a%20p%2C%20p%5E2%20%2B%20q%5E2%20-1%7D%2C%20%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bp%2Cq%7D%5D) to get the following relation between $a$, $b$

$$4 - 3 a^2 - 2 a b + a^3 b - 3 b^2 + 2 a^2 b^2 + a b^3=0$$
which is equivalent to
$$(a-b)^2 = \frac{ ((a+b)^2 -4)^2}{(a+b)^2 + 4}$$
or
$$v^2 = \frac{ (u^2 -1)^2}{u^2 + 1}$$
where $u=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $v=\frac{a-b}{2}$.

The contour curve is the union of two graphs
$$v = \pm \frac{ u^2 -1}{\sqrt{u^2 + 1}}$$

$\bf{Added:}$ With trigonometry, one  checks that for
$$a = \frac{\sin 3 \theta}{\cos \theta}\\
b= \frac{\cos 3 \theta}{\sin \theta}$$
we have
$$\frac{a+b}{2} = \cot 2 \theta \\
\frac{a b -1}{2} = \cos 4 \theta$$

and from here we get a relation between $a$, $b$

Comment: I didn't mention in my question that (because it is irrelevant), but if you are interested, in the above problem (associated with the other), $a, b$ are $\frac{c(\sqrt3+1)}{(x+y)}$ and $\frac{c(\sqrt3-1)}{(x-y)}$ where $c$ is constant. Though don't bother about  this :)

Comment: @Flagged: You are very welcome. I am surprised that the relation turns out to have a neat form. Let me examine the other question now.

Comment: Please wait and sorry... there should be a $4$ in the denominator of both fractions. (e.g. $\frac{c(\sqrt3+1)}{4(x+y)}$) And since you are going to check the other question, $c$ is actually $a$ there.

Comment: @Flagged: About the other question, solving the system gets a solution in terms of $b=\frac{\sin 3 \theta}{\sin\theta}$ and $a=\frac{\sin 3 \theta}{\cos \theta}$ ( a bit different from this problem). With trig, we get $\frac{a^2}{b^2} = \frac{3-b}{1+b} = \tan^2 \theta$. Your problem seems to be inspired, but not directly connected to that problem. Cheers!

Comment: @Stranger: From the WA equation, I did a SymmetricReduce to express it in terms of $a+b$, $a-b$, mostly because the shape of the level curve showed that there were two analytic branches.  Btw, the expression for $(ab-1)/2$ ( which I think takes care of the problem and is interesting) I found after looking at the simplifed formula. Good to see you back.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, BTW, Here's my method ------ We have  
$$\frac{b+a}2=\frac{\cos2\theta}{\sin2\theta}=u$$  
$$\frac{b-a}2=\frac{\cos4\theta}{\sin2\theta}=v$$  
  
Squaring the second equation gives,  
$$v^2=\frac{\cos^2 4\theta}{\sin^2 2\theta}$$  
$$v^2=\frac{(\cos^2 2\theta-\sin^2 2\theta)^2}{\sin^2 2\theta}$$  
$$v^2=\frac{\sin^42\theta\left(\dfrac{\cos^2 2\theta}{\sin^2 2\theta}-1\right)^2}{\sin^2 2\theta}$$  
$$v^2=\frac{\sin^2 2\theta(u^2-1)^2}{\cos^2 2\theta+\sin^2 2\theta}$$  
$$v^2=\frac{(u^2-1)^2}{\dfrac{\cos^2 2\theta}{\sin^2 2\theta}+1}$$  
$$v^2=\frac{(u^2-1)^2}{u^2+1}$$

Comment: @Stranger: This is interesting! I could not do it by hand even in the ancestral times.

Answer (score 3):

My first idea after seeing the problem is to say that
$$
a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta=1
$$
From this we get
$$
a^2(1+\cos2\theta)+b^2(1-\cos2\theta)=2
$$
whence
$$
\cos2\theta=\frac{2-a^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}
$$
But we also have
$$
\frac{\sin^23\theta}{a^2}+\frac{\cos^23\theta}{b^2}=1
$$
whence
$$
b^2\sin^23\theta+a^2\cos^23\theta=a^2b^2
$$
and, similarly to the above,
$$
\cos6\theta=\frac{2a^2b^2-a^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}
$$
Now use the identity for $\cos3x$ in terms of $\cos x$.