# Solving $\cos^2 x+\cos^2 2x +\cos^2 3x=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math

I picked this up from the IMO 1962.

> Solve for $x$: 
>   $$\cos^2 x+\cos^2 2x +\cos^2 3x=1$$

At first I thought it was trivial to bring this in an IMO, but I realized approaching it directly brings a power of 6 which is not all too friendly.

Is there a sneaky way to solve this?

Comment: I don't have a general solution, but pugging in $\frac{\pi}{6}$ works. Also, if $x$ is a solution then so is $-x$. Thus, $-\frac{\pi}{6}$ must work too. But I'm not sure if this is all of them

Comment: Better than what I have so far, thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use double angles to get the equivalent equation 
$$\cos(0x) + \cos(2x) + \cos(4x) + \cos(6x) = 0.$$

Pair (first and last term) and (middle ones) to get the equivalent form
$$\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(3x) = 0.$$

Answer (score 5):

Use double angle identify to write the equation as

$$\cos 2x+\cos 4x +\cos 6x+1=0$$

Let $t=\cos 2x$. Then, the equation is

$$2t^3+t^2-t=0\implies t(t+1)(2t-1)=0$$

Thus, $\cos 2x= 0,\> -1, \> \frac12$ and the solutions are 
$x = \frac\pi4+\frac{n\pi}2,\> \frac\pi2+ n\pi,\> \pm\frac\pi6+\frac{2n\pi}3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t:=\cos^2x$.

We have

$$t+(2t-1)^2+(4t-3)^2t=1$$

or

$$16t^3-20t^2+6t=0.$$

The roots are $0,\dfrac12,\dfrac34$, nothing really difficult.

Comment: $(4t-3)^2t$ should be $(4t^2-3)t$

Comment: @JeanMarie: no, it should not. Read again.

Comment: My bad. Sorry. I had thought $t=\cos x$...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b)

$$\cos^2x+\cos^22x=\cos^22x-\sin^2x+1=\cos(2x+x)\cos(2x-x)+1$$

Finally by http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

$$\cos3x+\cos x=2\cos2x\cos x$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
use the identity 
$${\displaystyle \cos ^{2}\alpha +\cos ^{2}\beta +\cos ^{2}\gamma =-2\cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma +1\,}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\cos^2x\left(1+(4\cos^2x-3)^2\right)=4\sin^2x\cos^2x,$$ which gives $$\cos{x}=0$$ and $$x=90^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k,$$ where $k$ is an integer number, or $$1+(4\cos^2x-3)^2=4-4\cos^2x,$$ which is
$$8\cos^4x-10\cos^2x+3=0$$ or
$$(4\cos^2x-3)(2\cos^2x-1)=0$$ or
$$(2\cos2x-1)\cos2x=0,$$ which gives
$$x=\pm30^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k$$ or $$x=45^{\circ}+90^{\circ}k.$$