# Evaluating $ 4\sum^{30}_{n=1} n\;T(n)$, where $T(n) = \cos^2(30^\circ -n) - \cos(30^\circ -n)\cos(30^\circ +n) +\cos^2(30^\circ +n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> For $n$ measured in degrees, let 
>   $$T(n) = \cos^2(30^\circ -n) - \cos(30^\circ -n)\cos(30^\circ +n) +\cos^2(30^\circ +n)$$
>   Evaluate $$ 4\sum^{30}_{n=1} n \cdot T(n)$$

I have tried to use double-angle identities but got stuck with the coefficient $n$. I am new to trig, so I probably miss some advanced concepts.

Comment: $\cos^2(30^\circ -n) - \cos(30^\circ -n)\cos(30^\circ +n) +\cos^2(30^\circ +n)=\frac{3}{4}$ for any $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ginger bread,

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b)

$$\cos^2x+\cos^2y=1+\cos(x-y)\cos(x+y)$$

$$\cos x\cos y=\dfrac{\cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)}2$$

If $\cos(x+y)=\dfrac12\iff x+y=360^\circ m\pm60^\circ,$

$$T(n)=1-\dfrac{\dfrac12}2=?$$

Here $x=30^\circ-n,y=30^\circ+n$

Comment: This manipulation is clever and elegant

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$\cos^2(30^\circ-n)-\cos(30^\circ-n)\cos(30^\circ+n)+\cos^2(30^\circ+n)=\cos(30^\circ-n)[\cos(30^\circ-n)-\cos(30^\circ+n)] +\cos^2(30^\circ+n)=(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos n +\frac{1}{2}\sin n )2\sin30°\sin n +(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos n -\frac{1}{2}\sin n )^2=
\frac{3}{4}$$

$$ 4\sum^{30}_{n=1} n \cdot T(n)=4\frac{3}{4}(1+2+\cdots+30)=1395 $$

Answer (score 1):

Well it uses a neat identity that cos(A+B)*cos(A-B)= cos^2A-sin^2B

just expand cos(30-n) = cos30cos(n) +sin30sin(n). and similarly cos(30+n) for middle term

cos(30-n)cos(30+n) = cos^2(30) - sin^2(n)

now simplify to get T(n) = 3/4
hence ans is sum= 3*30*31/2 = 1395.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. With [proper formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it would be even more helpful.

Comment: Most straightforward answer. The identity will come in handy

Comment: @J.G and the pianist thanks and would improve formatting in future.