# In $\Delta ABC$, if $2\cos\frac{A-C}{2}=\frac{a+c}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2-ac}}$, then choose the right options

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

1. $B=\frac{\pi}{3}$
2. $B=C$
3. $A, B, C$ are in arithmetic progression
4. $B+C=A$

$$2\cos \frac {A-C}{2}=\frac{\sin A+\sin C}{\sqrt{\sin^2 A+\sin^2 C -\sin A\sin C}}$$

$$\sqrt {\sin^2A+\sin^2C-\sin A\sin C}=\sin \frac{A+C}{2}$$

$$\sin^2A+\sin^2C-\sin A\sin C = \cos ^2 \frac B2$$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue with

\begin{align}
& \sin^2A+\sin^2C-\sin A\sin C - \cos ^2 \frac B2 \\
=&(\sin A - \sin C)^2 + \frac12( \cos (A-C)-\cos (A+C))- \frac12(1+ \cos B) \\
=& 4\cos^2 \frac{A+C}2 \sin^2 \frac{A-C}2 - \frac12(1-  \cos (A-C)) \\
=& 4\sin^2 \frac{B}2 \sin^2 \frac{A-C}2 - \sin^2 \frac{A-C}2  \\
= &(4\sin^2 \frac{B}2 -1)\sin^2 \frac{A-C}2 \\
\end{align}

which leads to $\sin \frac B2 = \frac12 $ or $\sin\frac{A-C}2 =0$. Thus, $ B= \frac\pi3$ or $A =C$

Comment: How would you prove that ABC are in an AP?

Comment: @Aditya - I don’t think they are in A.P.

Comment: But that is the right answer

Comment: @Aditya - The correct answer is (1)

Comment: I found plenty of the solutions proving the converse

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-in-a-triangle-abc-the-angles-abc-are-in-apthen-displaystylefrac-ac/
There you go

Comment: @Aditya - just realized that, if $B=\frac\pi3$, $A+C = 2B, hence in AP

Answer (score 1):

In the standard notation we obtain:
$$4\cos^2\frac{\alpha-\gamma}{2}=\frac{(a+c)^2}{a^2-ac+c^2}$$ or
$$1+\cos(\alpha-\gamma)=\frac{(a+c)^2}{2(a^2-ac+c^2)}$$ or
$$\cos\alpha\cos\gamma+\sin\alpha\sin\gamma=\frac{-a^2+4ac-c^2}{2(a^2-ac+c^2)}$$ or
$$\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}+\frac{2S}{bc}\cdot\frac{2S}{ab}=\frac{-a^2+4ac-c^2}{2(a^2-ac+c^2)}$$ or
$$\frac{b^4-(a^2-c^2)^2+\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}{2b^2ac}=\frac{-a^2+4ac-c^2}{a^2-ac+c^2}$$ or
$$\frac{b^2(a^2+c^2)-(a^2-c^2)^2}{2b^2ac}=\frac{-a^2+4ac-c^2}{a^2-ac+c^2}$$ or
$$(a^2-c^2)^2(a^2+c^2-ac-b^2)=0,$$ which gives $$a=c$$ or
$$\beta=60^{\circ}.$$
We see that any option may be wrong.

Comment: In the second line, shouldn’t LHS be multiplied by 2?

Comment: @Aditya No. I used $16S^2=\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4).$

Comment: No I meant for $4\cos^2 \frac x2 = 2(\cos x +1)$

Comment: @Aditya It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Law of Sines](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofSines.html)

$$\dfrac{c+a}{2\cos\dfrac{C-A}2}=\cdot=2R\cos\dfrac B2>0$$

$$\implies\left(2R\cos\dfrac B2\right)^2=4R^2(\sin^2C+\sin^2A-\sin C\sin A)$$

$$\dfrac{1+\cos B}2=1-(\cos^2C-\sin^2A)-\dfrac{\cos(C-A)-\cos(C+A)}2$$

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),
$$1+\cos B=2-2\cos(C-A)\cos (C+A)-[\cos(C-A)-\cos(C+A)]$$

Finally, using $\cos(C+A)=\cdots=-\cos B$

We get $$(\cos(C-A)-1)(2\cos B-1)=0$$

Can you take it from here?