# How to show $\cos^2A + \cos^2B = \frac{1}{2} \cos(2A + \frac{\pi}{3}) + 1$ more efficiently

Tags: trigonometry, alternative-proof

> In $\Delta ABC$, $C = \frac{\pi}{3}$, how to prove that $\cos^2A + \cos^2B = \frac{1}{2} \cos(2A + \frac{\pi}{3}) + 1$?

My attempt:
\begin{align}
L.H.S 
&= \cos^2A + \cos^2B \\
&= \cos^2A + \cos^2(A + \frac{\pi}{3}) \\
&= \frac{1 + \cos 2A}{2} + \frac{1 + \cos(2A + \frac{2}{3}\pi)}{2} \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cos 2A + \frac{1}{2}(\cos 2A \cos\frac{2\pi}{3} - \sin \frac{2\pi}{3}\sin 2A) \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{4} \cos 2A - \frac{\sqrt 3}{4} \sin 2A \\
R.H.S
&= \frac{1}{2}\cos (2A + \frac{\pi}{3}) + 1 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\cos 2A \cos\frac{\pi}{3} - \sin \frac{\pi}3 \sin 2A) + 1 \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{4}\cos 2A - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \sin 2A \\
&= L.H.S
\end{align}
I wonder if there is a way to show it more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b)

$$\cos^2A+\cos^2B=\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)+1$$

Now $A+B=\pi-C=?$

$A-B=A-(\pi-A-C)=A-\left(\pi-A-\dfrac\pi3\right)=?$

Answer (score 1):

At the step
$$\frac {1+\cos 2A}2+\frac{1+\cos(2A+\frac23\pi)}2$$

we can use the identity

$$\cos \alpha+\cos\beta=2\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\right)$$

to obtain

$$\begin{align}\frac {1+\cos 2A}2+\frac{1+\cos(2A+\frac23\pi)}2 &= 1+\frac12(\cos2A+\cos(2A+\frac23\pi))
\\&=1+\cos\left(\frac{2A+(2A+\frac23\pi)}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{2A-(2A+\frac23\pi)}2\right)
\\&=1+\cos\left(2A+\frac\pi3\right)\cos\left(-\frac\pi3\right)
\\&=1+\frac12\cos\left(2A+\frac\pi3\right)
\end{align}$$